# How to implement a hover tip aside of a collapsed menu

Tags: html, css

Consider the following collapsed side menu:

```css
.collapsedSideMenu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menuItem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.menuItem:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: grey;
}

.menuTitle {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsedSideMenu">
  <div class="menuItem">AB</div>
  <div class="menuTitle">Option AB</div>
  <div class="menuItem">CD</div>
  <div class="menuTitle">Option CD</div>
  <div class="menuItem">EF</div>
  <div class="menuTitle">Option EF</div>
</div>
```

I need to show the title (`menuTitle`) on mouse hover of the respective option (`menuItem`), showing at the right side of the collpsed option.

Something like:

```
| AB |
| CD | Option AB | << On hover over CD
| EF |
```

Hwo to do it using CSS/HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your code like below:

```css
.collapsedSideMenu {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.menuItem {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.menuTitle {
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  transform:translateY(-100%);
  display:none;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: grey;
}
.menuItem:hover + .menuTitle,
.menuTitle:hover{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsedSideMenu">
  <div class="menuItem">AB</div>
  <div class="menuTitle">Option AB</div>
  <div class="menuItem">CD</div>
  <div class="menuTitle">Option CD</div>
  <div class="menuItem">EF</div>
  <div class="menuTitle">Option EF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lost the hover background-color change over the original collapsed item...

Comment: @Mendes you can add it back, I simply ket the relevant code and removed the non-relevant for the demo